# C++ - The right way of type rebinding-resolving?

Tags: c++

i have the following code snippets:

```
namespace X86X64
{
   struct IMM8 {};
}

namespace X86
{
    using namespace X86X64;

    struct RM8 {};

    template <class _Traits>
    struct MOV_Instruction
    {
        typedef typename _Traits::RM8 RM8;

        void mov(const RM8& rm, const IMM8& imm)
        {}
    };
}

namespace X64
{
  using namespace X86X64;

  struct RM8 {};
  struct RM64 {};

  struct Traits
  {
    typedef RM8 RM8;
  };

  struct MOV_Instruction : public X86::MOV_Instruction<Traits>
  {
     using X86::MOV_Instruction<Traits>::mov;

     void mov(const RM64& rm, const IMM8& imm)
     {}
  };
}
```

When i use no traits, i get an error,  that the compiler cannot find any operator converting an X64::RM8 to X86::RM8, when instantiating MOV_Instruction.

The namespaces X86 and X64 must have their own seperate RM8 types with different underlying base types.

I wanna only use an:

```
using namespace X86 | X64

MOV_Instruction i;
i.mov(RM8(), IMM8());
```

and want the compiler to select the right RM8 type depending on the used namespace and Koenig lookup.
Is their a better way to do this without a traits to rebind or resolve the right type?

I could make X86::RM8 and X64::RM8 the same type, but i don't wanna strive for that.

Thanks
Martin

Answer (score 1):

```
This compiles fine using VC9: 

namespace X86X64 {
    struct IMM8 {};
}

namespace X86 {
    using namespace X86X64;

    struct RM8 {};

    template <class Traits>
    struct MOV_Instruction {
        typedef typename Traits::RM8 RM8;
        void mov(const RM8& rm, const IMM8& imm) {}
    };
}

namespace X64 {
    using namespace X86X64;

    struct RM8 {};
    struct RM64 {};

    struct Traits {
        typedef RM8 RM8;
    };

    struct MOV_Instruction : public X86::MOV_Instruction<Traits> {
        using X86::MOV_Instruction<Traits>::mov;
        void mov(const RM64& rm, const IMM8& imm) {}
    };
}

int main()
{
    //using namespace X86; 
    using namespace X64;

    MOV_Instruction i;
    i.mov(RM8(), IMM8());

    return 0;
}
```

Note that can't have both using directives, since that would make `MOV_Instruction` ambiguous.

Also, I changed `_Traits` to `Traits`, since identifiers starting with an underscore, followed by a capital letter, are reserved to the implementation. (You might attract a macro from some header to trample over your code and cause *very* strange compiler errors.)

Answer (score 0):

One more way

```
namespace X86X64
{
   struct IMM8 {};
}
```

namespace X86
{
    using namespace X86X64;
    typedef struct RM8 {} RM8;

```
template < class T = RM8 >
struct MOV_Instruction
{
    typedef T RM8;

    void mov(const RM8& rm, const IMM8& imm)
    {}
};
```

}

namespace X64
{
  using namespace X86X64;

typedef struct RM8 {} RM8;
  struct RM64 {};

template < class T = RM8 >
  struct MOV_Instruction : public X86::MOV_Instruction
  {
     using X86::MOV_Instruction::mov;

```
 void mov(const RM64& rm, const IMM8& imm)
 {}
```

};
}

int main() {
        using namespace X86;

`MOV_Instruction<> i;
    i.mov(RM8(), IMM8());
    return 0;`

}